# How Can I update Request value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I'm in the middle of a personal project that is going to be a file manager, at this moment the part of taking the file and moving it to a custom directory is working, but the part of uploading this "dir" to DB isn't working, this is the "store" function of my Controller.

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'path' => 'required',
        'id_class' => 'required'
    ]);

    $file = $request->path;
    $fileName = bin2hex(random_bytes(5)) . ".pdf";
    $folder = "files/" . str_pad($request['id_user'], 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT)
              . "/" . date("Y-m-d");
    $path = $file->storeAs(
        $folder,
        $fileName
    );
    $request = $request->merge(['path' => $path]);
    if (Presentation::create($request->all())) {
        return redirect()->route('presentation.create')
                  ->with('success', "Presentation successfully exported {$path}");
    }
}
```

You can see that I'm displaying "$path", the received message is

> "Presentation successfully exported files/000001/2019-10-09/a1c3b14192.pdf"

but in my table on Xampp is receiving "D:\xampp\tmp\phpBDBA.tmp".

[image]

Just for a possible lack of information, this is my Table:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can merge inputs into the request via `merge` but the file still exists in a separate source. In this case you are setting an input, `path`, to your stored file path you have generated but the `path` var in the files still exists as a `UploadedFile` object. The `all` method merges the files into the inputs in a way where the files take priority. In your case to only get inputs (not including files) you can call `input()` instead of `all()`.

```
Presentation::create($request->input())
```

Comment: Wait, was that ever this simple? Thank you, you're the best :D

Answer (score 0):

You can not merge a request like this. The reason you can find printing the request  `dd($request);`

```
$request = $request->merge(['path' => $path]);
```

You can try like this:

```
$requestData = collect($request->only(['path', 'id_class']));
// or 
// $requestData = collect($request->all());

$requestData = $requestData->merge(['path' => $path]);

Presentation::create($requestData);
```

Hope this helps.